# What is the best way to cluster this kind of data?

Tags: clustering, statistics, descriptive-statistics

I have data that looks like this:
[image]

The chart on the left is the trend and the smaller chart on the right is the box plot showing the distribution of means. Each color is the output of a particular tool. I dont need to do an ANOVA and Tukey tests on it because it can easily be seen that there are statistically significant differences between the tools.
However, I would like to group/cluster the tools based on their mean.

For example, visually speaking, one can separate all the tools into 4 groups. 4 tools with a mean around `32`, 12 tools with a mean around `30`, 5 tools whose variance is quite high, and whose mean don't really fall into a particular group and the rest whose mean is around `30`.

**Update:**

I have used the k-means clustering technique and the Hierarchical Agglomeration techniques. However, I have to specify the number of clusters in advance. Is there any clustering technique where I don't have to specify the number of clusters a-priori?

Comment: most clustering algorithms can cluster anything given the approprate distance metric

Comment: It looks like you have good labelled data and that the number of clusters/classes is predefined, so why not using supervised classification? This would certainly give better results.

Comment: @Erwan I was thinking more of unsupervised. Since all I want to do is cluster based on the mean. What would I supervise it on?

Comment: In a supervised setting you could decide yourself what should be the 4 groups, but maybe that's not what you want. The problem is a bit unusual to me so I'm not sure what to recommend, but I'd say that K-means is worth trying yes.

Comment: @Erwan Would I be able to use K-Means if one of my axis was labelled and not continuous?
I basically want to do the clustering on the smaller chart to the right of the trend. There, the x-axis is labelled (Tool Name) and the y-axis is continuous (Mean of Tool output)

Comment: Technically yes, you can use categorical variables as features by converting the values to boolean features using one-hot encoding. However I don't see how that would make sense here: if the goal is to cluster the instances where each instance is for one tool, then the tool id is irrelevant since they are all different. So imho you should do the clustering with only the mean, or possibly adding other features representing other statistics like standard deviation, median, quantiles, etc.

Comment: I agree. I am doing the clustering only on the mean.  However, the reason I wanted the tool id is so that I know which group of tools should correspond to which clustered mean. Like student id and their test scores. I can cluster a bunch of students that generally got around the same scores to just one score.

Comment: And the reason I need the clustered tool-ids to the clustered mean association is because my final output is not a visual scatter plot like most cluster algorithms outputs. I will be having a table that has the clustered tools on one column and their clustered mean in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hierarchical clustering, both agglomerative and divisive, you do not have to pre-specify the number of clusters. You can create all possible clusters and then select the number cluster to use at the end.